# Stellar-core transactions not supported

Tags: stellar.js

I am getting tx_not_supported. I have compiled stellar-core 1.15.0 and launched the network. I am able to use the horizon and see the root account balance. However when trying a transaction/create account, I am getting tx_not_supported.

Comment: Can you add more information? Which SDK (and version) are you using? Which version of the protocol are you using (typically you need latest SDK against later version of the protocol)? XDR of the transaction envelope result would also help.

Comment: actually this looks to be a duplicate of https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/4357/getting-tx-not-supported-on-steller-core-prod-v1-15-0 that already has some of that information